# How to bind properties of class that might be null - sign of bad design

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

I am running into a scenario where I am binding to a property from my viewmodel in my xaml view where the VM property might be null. This causes my view not to load because I believe that I am getting a NullReferenceException.

VM:

```
 public class PersonDetailViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public Person CurrentPerson
        {
            get => currentPerson;
            set => SetProperty(ref currentPerson, value);
        }

        private Person currentPerson;

        public bool IsBobsFriendsVisible => FriendNamedBob?.Friends?.Count > 0;
        public Person FriendNamedBob => CurrentPerson?.Friends?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Bob");

        public PersonDetailViewModel()
        {
            CurrentPerson = new Person()
            {
                Name = "Henry",
                Friends = new List<Person>() { new Person() { Name = "Rachel" } }
            };
        }
    }
```

XAML:

```
<ContentPage>
    <ContantPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Bob's Friends Count:" IsVisible="{Binding IsBobsFriendsVisible}" />
            <Label Text="{Binding FriendNamedBob.Friends.Count}" IsVisible="{Binding IsBobsFriendsVisible}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

This line is causing the issue obviously since `FriendNamedBob` is null:

```
<Label Text="{Binding FriendNamedBob.Friends.Count}" IsVisible="{Binding IsBobsFriendsVisible}" />
```

What is the recommended technique for dealing with this scenario? Is this a sign of bad design?

---

**Update:**
It seems that a `FallBackValue` of sorts (`TargetNullValue` included) is not yet supported in Xamarin.Forms https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1803 also the DataTrigger does not work when checking for null https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=57863

Thus, **this is not a duplicate** (yet) -- what are people currently doing in this situation?

Comment: How can I "unduplicate" this question? I researched the suggestion and I have good reason to believe it is not a duplicate - does Stackoverflow really force me to delete and re-add the question? @BradleyDotNET

Comment: flag and ask a moderator to re-open

Comment: @Jason I did. Very confused.

Comment: you should be good now

Comment: I'd suggest that you create a property in your VM that handles the null case correctly and bind to it, instead of using the complex binding expression that you have

Comment: @Jason true... Just would require a lot of properties in my actual scenario however perhaps that isn't the worst thing in the world given that it would solve the problem. Was hoping for an "easier" way.

Answer (score 0):

Here let me explain to handle the Null binding in Xaml. And  i used same format to bind the list of object in xaml and it's work.

```
Public Class Person
{
  Public Person()
  {
  }
      int id=0;--- Here we are doing default Initialization of object to handle default null values 
        public int ID
        {
            get
            {
                return id;
            }
            set
            {
                id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        string name="";--- Here we are doing default Initialization of object to handle default null values 
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return name;
            }
            set
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
}
```

Now we can bind directly in XAML